# Unit test of a method that has another method which returns void

Tags: java, junit, mockito

My actual method to be tested:

```
public Boolean deletePatientChart(IPRDTO clientDto, Long bookShelfId,
            Long patientChartId) throws BusinessException, Exception {

        BookShelves bookShelves = bookshelvesRepository.findOne(bookShelfId);
        if (bookShelves.getType().equals("SECONDARY")) {
            UserChartShelves userChartShelves = bookshelvesRepository
                    .getUserPatientChartToDelete(bookShelfId, patientChartId);
            if (userChartShelves != null) {
                userChartShelvesRepository.delete(userChartShelves.getId());
                return true;
            } else {
                throw new BusinessException("noItemToDelete");
            }
        }
        throw new BusinessException("noDeletion");
    }
```

My test code:

```
@Test
public void testDeletePatientChart() throws BusinessException, Exception {
    BookShelves bookShelves =new BookShelves();
    UserChartShelves userChartShelves  =new UserChartShelves();
    Mockito.when(this.bookshelvesRepository.findOne(1l))
            .thenReturn(bookShelves);
    Mockito.when(this.bookshelvesRepository.getUserPatientChartToDelete(1l, 1l))
    .thenReturn(userChartShelves);
    boolean status = this.bookshelfServiceImpl.deletePatientChart(
            clientDto, 1l, 1l);
    Assert.assertTrue(status);
}
```

In my test code I have not made a mock for

```
"userChartShelvesRepository.delete(userChartShelves.getId());"
```

How can i write a mock for this this delete method?

Comment: So your method either returns `true`, or throws an exception? Do you have a `return false; ` at the end of the method, just before te closing `}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Mockito.doNothing().when(userChartShelvesRepository).delete(Mockito.anyObject());
```

or

```
Mockito.doThrow(new Exception()).when(userChartShelvesRepository).delete(Mockito.anyObject());
```

if you want to throw exception

Answer (score 0):

You can use ArgumentCaptor to capture the passed in argument and verify it

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;


public class TestUnit {

    @Test 
    public void test() {
        TestObj obj = mock(TestObj.class);
        ArgumentCaptor<Long> argCapture = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Long.class);
        doNothing().when(obj).delete(argCapture.capture());
        obj.delete(10L);
        assertEquals(10L, argCapture.getValue().longValue());
    }

    private static interface TestObj {

        public void delete(Long id);

    }
}
```